# How to select different rows base on conditions in Spark sql

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I created a rank column base on `num` column and grouped by name. I'm trying to implement logic to `select the colour value in the first row if num is not 0, otherwise use the colour value from the second row or 3rd row, where the num is not 0` For example for Name A, colour yellow should be selected. For Name B, colour green should be selected.
Could someone please help to suggest how to do this? Thank you.

```
Name.    colour     num.     rank 
 A.       blue       0         1
 A        yellow.    300       2
 B        green      100.      1
 B        brown      500.      2
```

Comment: It might be useful to include your original query that has produced your current results, as well as some sample data from the source table/s - depending on exactly what you've done to achieve these current results, it may be a simple modification to your existing query, or it may be that you'll need to use your current query as a derived table, and then add a supplementary query to achieve your final results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use first use `filter` to exclude `0`s, followed by a `Window partition` to assign `row_number`, and then another `filter` to filter out values thare are not `1`.

`Example`

```scala
df
  .filter(col("num").gt(0))
  .withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy(col("rank"))))
  .filter(col("row_number").equalTo(1))
  .drop("row_number")
```

`Output`

```
+----+------+---+----+
|name|color |num|rank|
+----+------+---+----+
|A   |yellow|300|2   |
|B   |green |100|1   |
+----+------+---+----+
```

This only works under the assumption that the combination of `name` and `num` are unique, if this is not the case, then further adjustments are needed. Also, if you show the code that leads to your mentioned table, this problem could be solved in a more efficient way (probably). Good luck!